# Etymologie : »Rat« und »Rede«

Tags: etymology

Entstammen die Wörter »Rat« (»raten«) und »Rede« (»reden«) einer gemeinsamen etymologischen Wurzel?

**HINTERGRUND**

Nach wiktionary.org ist die Etymologie der Wörter wie folgt:

> **[Rat](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Rat#Etymology)** : From Old High German rāt, from Proto-Germanic *rēdaz (compare Dutch raad, English rede, Old English ræd).
>   **[raten](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/raten#Etymology)** : From Old High German rātan, from Proto-Germanic *rēdaną. Compare Low German raden, Dutch raden, English read, Danish råde.
>   **[Rede](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Rede#Etymology)** : From Middle High German rede, from Old High German redia, radia (“speech, view, opinion”), from Proto-Germanic *raþjǭ, *raþjō (“accountability, speech”); from the same root as reden (“to talk, to speak”). Cognate with Latin ratiō (“account, reason, proof”) and English rede (“counsel”).
>   **[reden](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/reden#Etymology)** : From Middle High German reden, from Old High German redōn, rediōn (“to speak”), a derivative of reda, redia (“speech, word, opinion, view, mind”), from Proto-Germanic *raþjǭ, *raþjō (“accountability, speech”). See Rede.

Wie Sie sehen können, gibt es keine offensichtliche Überschneidung, aber man hätte erwartet, dass zwei Wörter, die so ähnlich im Aussehen und Sinn sind, auch etymologisch verwandt seien.

Auch nach wiktionary.org ist das englisch Wort »rede« mit dem deutschen »Rat« verwandt.

> **[rede](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/rede#Etymology_1)** : From Middle English rede, from Old English rǣd, from Proto-Germanic *rēdaz. Cognate with Danish råd, Dutch raad, German Rat, Swedish råd. Indo-European cognates include Latin ratiō (“reason, judgment, counsel”).

Comment: Möglich, aber unwahrscheinlich. Ich finde deine Erwartungshaltung etwas optimistisch: Nur weil viele Buchstaben gleich sind, muss nicht gleich eine ethymologische Verwandtschaft existieren. "Rad" und "Reede"  sind auch sehr ähnlich... Vor allem die Verbindungen *Hausrat*, *Unrat* und *Gerät* zeigen in eine ganz andere Richtung, die mit *reden* gar nichts zu tun hat.

Comment: Ein Problem der Frage ist, was du unter "etymologischer Wurzel" verstehst. Eine "Wurzel" gibt es ja nicht, sondern nur tiefer liegende "Gabelungen". Wenn man weit genug zurückgeht, sind ja wahrscheinlich fast alle Worte miteinander verwandt.

Comment: Rede ist verwandt mit Latin ratiō (von ratus). DWDS beschreibt, "raten bedeutet ursprünglich ‘überlegen, (aus)sinnen’". Das ist schon nahe an der Bedeutung von ratus. Die Grimms schrieben im Lemma zu Rat ebenfalls ein lateinisches Zitat, das rationibus enthaelt. Leider kann ich kein Latein. Einfach mal den Links auf wiktionary folgen! Ich habe dort aber keine eindeutige Entwicklung gefunden. Die Verwandschaft von rēdaną (wird zu raten) zu reden muesste hier aber erstmal widerlegt werden, denn das ist die Fragestellung.

Comment: @jonathan.scholbach Yep - führt alles auf einen einzigen neandertalerischen Grunzlaut zurück...

Comment: Yes, I should have said 'vielleicht' and 'könnte' somewhere in there for the sake of the poor Neanderthal.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Altphilologen sagen vermutlich, die Begriffe seien nicht direkt verwandt, da zwei unterschiedliche Indo-Germanische Wurzeln rekonstruiert wurden: [Hreh₁dʰ-](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Reconstruction:Proto-Indo-European/Hreh%E2%82%81d%CA%B0-) und [h₂er-](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Reconstruction:Proto-Indo-European/h%E2%82%82er-). Den Unterschied kann ich aber nicht beurteilen.

Das bedeutet aber besonders in Anbetracht der sinnverwandten Bedeutung noch nicht, ältere Verwandschaft und gegenseitige Beeinflussung könnten ausgeschlossen werden, da die rekonstruierten Wurzeln keine direkt gesprochenen Worte darstellen, zumal die Aussprache nicht bekannt ist und vermutlich nicht einheitlich war.